# calculate area intersected between ellipses - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, intersection

I'm aiming to calculate the area that intersects between two ellipses. The following computes the area between two fixed coordinates but I'm hoping iterate this process using moving coordinates for one ellipse, while keeping the second ellipse fixed.

Using below, `ellipse1` will remain constant and `ellipse2` will use the coordinates from `X` and `Y` in the `df`.

The intended output will hopefully return the area at each point in time rounded to 2 decimal places as a separate column labelled `'Area'`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({        
    'Time' : [1,2,3,4,5],                               
    'X' : [3.0,4.5,5.0,10.0,3.0],
    'Y' : [1.0,0.0,-1.0,-2.0,-3.0],         
    })

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry.point import Point
from shapely import affinity
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np

def create_ellipse(center, lengths, angle = 0):

    """
    create a shapely ellipse. adapted from
    https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/243462
    """
    circ = Point(center).buffer(1)
    ell = affinity.scale(circ, int(lengths[0]), int(lengths[1]))
    ellr = affinity.rotate(ell, angle)

    return ellr

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,6))

ax.set_xlim([-20,20])
ax.set_ylim([-20,20])

ellipse1 = create_ellipse((0,0),(5,10),0)
verts1 = np.array(ellipse1.exterior.coords.xy)
patch1 = Polygon(verts1.T,color = 'red', alpha = 0.5)
ax.add_patch(patch1)

ellipse2 = create_ellipse((3.0,1.0),(5,5),0)
verts2 = np.array(ellipse2.exterior.coords.xy)
patch2 = Polygon(verts2.T,color = 'blue', alpha = 0.5)
ax.add_patch(patch2)

##compute intersect 
intersect = ellipse1.intersection(ellipse2)
verts3 = np.array(intersect.exterior.coords.xy)
patch3 = Polygon(verts3.T, facecolor = 'none', edgecolor = 'black')
ax.add_patch(patch3)

##compute intersected area
print(intersect.area)
```

intended output:

```
   Time     X    Y   Area
0     1   3.0  1.0  56.51
1     2   4.5  0.0  46.99
2     3   5.0 -1.0  36.75
3     4  10.0 -2.0   0.00
4     5   3.0 -3.0  54.03
```

Comment: A circle is an ellipse, so why not just use the two-ellipses case? Anyway—I don't see a question here. What's breaking?

Comment: And explain what is wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: This is not trivial.  https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/AreaIntersectingEllipses.pdf

Comment: Sincere apologies. Question now updated to include more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you clearly, you're almost there ; all you need is to use a kind of loop in the dataframe. This would do the trick even if this may not be very efficient because of apply (the better way would probably to take the leap to geopandas, but this method here would be easier to understand for you I think) :

```
ellipse1 = create_ellipse((0,0),(5,10),0)

df['ellipse2']  = df[['X', 'Y']].apply(
        lambda xy:create_ellipse([*xy],(5,5),0),
        axis=1
        )
df['Area'] = df['ellipse2'].apply(lambda x: ellipse1.intersection(x).area)
df.drop('ellipse2', axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Returns

```
   Time     X    Y       Area
0     1   3.0  1.0  56.518719
1     2   4.5  0.0  41.997447
2     3   5.0 -1.0  36.746078
3     4  10.0 -2.0   0.000000
4     5   3.0 -3.0  54.029912
```